# relationship is not working - Laravel / phpunit / Sqlite

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, phpunit

I am coding a test, but I get some unexpected results in basic relationships. I use in memory sqlite db.

Those test were working well with MySQL db. I guess it has something to do with this migration.

```
$tournament0 = factory(Tournament::class)
    ->create(['user_id' => $this->simpleUser->id]);
```

`$this->simpleUser` is created on `setUp()` method

Now, when `$this->simpleUser->tournaments` should return `$tournament0`, but it is empty.

My relationship is working, it is not broken. Also, when testing manually in the browser, it works.

It just fail when using phpunit...

Here is the setUp() Method:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->simpleUser = factory(User::class)->create(['role_id' => Config::get('constants.ROLE_USER')]);

}
```

Full method that is failing:

```
/** @test */
public function dashboard_check_initial_state()
{
    Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'CountriesSeeder', '--database' => 'sqlite']);
    Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'TournamentLevelSeeder', '--database' => 'sqlite']);
    Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'CategorySeeder', '--database' => 'sqlite']);
    // Given
    $this->logWithUser($this->simpleUser);

    // Nothing has been created, default dash
    $this->visit('/')
        ->see(trans('core.create_new_tournament'))
        ->dontSee(trans('core.congigure_categories'));


    // Create 1 tournament
    $tournament0 = factory(Tournament::class)->create(['user_id' => $this->simpleUser->id]);

    $this->visit('/')
        ->seeInElement("p.text-muted", trans('core.no_tournament_created_yet'));

    // Now configure 2/2 categories

    $championship1 = factory(Championship::class)->create(['tournament_id' => $tournament0->id,'category_id'=>1]);
    $championship2 = factory(Championship::class)->create(['tournament_id' => $tournament0->id,'category_id'=>2]);

    factory(ChampionshipSettings::class)->create(['championship_id' => $championship1->id]);
    factory(ChampionshipSettings::class)->create(['championship_id' => $championship2->id]);

    $this->visit('/')
        ->seeInElement("span.text-muted", trans('core.congigure_categories'));
}
```

Any idea what can it be?

Comment: Can you show the `setUp` method and the whole test method that is failing?

Comment: yes, but please wait because it seems the issue is not the relationship, because Tournament::all() is returning empty collection

Comment: I added setUp method...still no clue what can it be :(

Comment: ...and the whole test method that is failing

Comment: ok, method has been added

Comment: I don't see `$this->simpleUser->tournaments` in the method. Is it the last assertion that's failing?

Comment: yes, the last assertion is failing. I don't use `$this->simpleUser->tournaments` in the test, but when I debug it, it is empty

Comment: Might be useful for you https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: @Kyslik I know what a FK is. Do you have any idea in mind?

Comment: You talk about migration, I don't see any migration in your post. I also do not see "stack trace".

Comment: I think it is more about seeding. But I checked the factories, and they work. I don't get the point of what you are trying to say

Comment: @Kyslik There is no stack trace. My test is expecting to see text on the page, and it just doesn't see it, that is why it is failing. Text is not present because user()->tournaments is returning empty result

Comment: Is phpunit.xml correctly set up? (I mean the **DB_CONNECTION** is **sqlite**) ?

Comment: Yes. In fact, my other 250 assertions are passing. This is the only bug in migration from mysql to sqlite